# Default scope ignoring dynamic value in condition

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord, default-scope

In my Activity model, I have a default scope:

```
default_scope where(:subject_id => Log.get_subject_id)
```

Problem is in Log.get_subject_id, default value is 0. Here is my Log model:

```
@@subject_id = 0
def self.set_subject_id(val)
  @@subject_id = val
end
def self.get_subject_id
  @@subject_id
end
```

When I change value of @@subject_id via Log.set_subject_id(10) in controller and then I try Activity.all, it always give me bad result. SQL:

```
SELECT "activities".* FROM "activities" WHERE "activities"."subject_id" = 0
```

Where is a problem? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With that form of `default_scope`, your `Log.get_subject_id` call will be evaluated when the class is parsed so you're really saying something like this:

```
default_scope where(:subject_id => 0)
```

However, you can use a block with [`default_scope`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Scoping/Default/ClassMethods.html#method-i-default_scope) to delay the evaluation of the scope until you try to use it and, presumably, `Log.get_subject_id` will have a useful value:

```
default_scope { where(:subject_id => Log.get_subject_id) }
```

Answer (score 1):

It is happening because of the scope caching, try wraping it with lambda:

```
default_scope lambda { { :conditions => { :subject_id => Log.get_subject_id } } }
```

Comment: You don't actually need the `lambda`, just a plain block will do the trick.

Comment: Since the original question was rails 3 syntax, I'd prefer the same as shown by @mu is too short

Comment: Eager-evaluated scopes (i.e. scopes not wrapped in a lambda) are deprecated in Rails 4, so they should always be wrapped in a lambda anyways.